# How do I get the slider hover to be a circle and also get rid of the line that forms above the slider?

Tags: html, css, slider

I currently have a slider with a hover, but is there a way to make the hover a circle that will appear as a circle in all browsers? Is there also a way to change the shape of the slider from a rectangle to a line? I have also tried to remove the random line that appears above the slider but can't seem to remove it, is there something obvious that I am missing?

Thank you!

```css
#container {
  padding: 300px 500px;
}

#frequencySlider {
  margin-top: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

#frequencyLabel {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

#toggleAudio {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: center;
  width: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #939393;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* Slider */

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #908e8e;
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}

.slider:hover {}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #0b38b4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #0b38b4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">

    <button id="toggleAudio">
      Click Here
    </button>
    <hr>
    <input type="range" min="100" max="4000" value="2000" step="1" class="slider" id="frequencySlider">
    <br>
    <p id="frequencyLabel">Frequency: 2000 Hz</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also works in IE11 -> [full example](https://github.com/tomik23/range-input-style)

```css
#frequencySlider {
  margin-top: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

#frequencyLabel {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

#toggleAudio {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: center;
  width: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #939393;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* Slider */

input[type=range] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(33, 150, 243);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(33, 150, 243);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(33, 150, 243);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7px;
}


/* fix for IE11 */

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: rgb(33, 150, 243);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="toggleAudio">
      Click Here
    </button>

  <label id="range" class="range">
      <input type="range" min="100" max="4000" value="2000" step="1" id="frequencySlider">
    </label>
  <br>
  <p id="frequencyLabel">Frequency: 2000 Hz</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonderful work! Is there a way to remove the grey line right above the red slider?

Comment: In your example, there is a line, but if you want to delete it, <hr>